Incorrect radius mapping with ClipRRect
I am trying to make cards on a CarouselView on flutter, however, when I put a border radius on it, there seems to be an incorrect mapping of what I put in to what I see. I want to put in a radius of 10, but what I get is something different - like radius 20+. It seems that the radius is being capped, because smaller inputs don't make a difference but setting a radius of like 40 does work.
I tried wrapping the ClipRRect in a card, but this inserts a radius of 10, but cuts the image off - as in the corners aren't rounded, because the image still has a larger radius and the card cuts the rounding off
My code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyPracticesCarousel extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPracticesCarousel({super.key});

  void viewPractice(BuildContext context)
  {
    print("Card pressed");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CarouselView(
      itemExtent: 320,
      shrinkExtent: 320,
      itemSnapping: true,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      onTap: (int index) {print("card pressed $index");},
      children: List<Widget>.generate(10, (int index) {
        return MyPracticeCard();
      }),
    );
  }
}



class MyPracticeCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPracticeCard({
    super.key,
  });

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/GP_front_image.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Colors.black,
                  Colors.transparent,
                ],
                begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                end: Alignment.topCenter,
                stops: [0.0, 0.75],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Positioned(
            bottom: 15,
            left: 15,
            right: 15,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "London Bridge General Practice",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 1,
                ),
                // SizedBox(height: 2), // Optionally, uncomment for spacing
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        "0.2 miles",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                    
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "4.5",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            ),
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            maxLines: 1,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 2,),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.star,
                            color: Colors.white, // Color of the star icon
                            size: 18, // Size of the star icon
                          ),
                          
                        ],
                      ),
                  
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 10,
            right: 10,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/HCA_logo.jpg",
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}





remove that ClipRRect entirely and instead add shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)), to  CarouselView - this is CarouselView that clips everything with that "big" radius

From your description it is not entirely clear where exactly the discrepancy is. but based on the code, you can add a borderRadius to your container's:
... 
child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), <--- here
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/GP_front_image.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), <-- here
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      Colors.black,
                      Colors.transparent,
                    ],
                    begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    end: Alignment.topCenter,
                    stops: [0.0, 0.75],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
        ...


I made these changes, and it didn't have an affect. For more clarity, if you look at the image at the bottom, it has a radius 10, I want the whole card to also have the same radius but, this is not the case. The radius of the whole widget is bigger than 10
